# How do i delete a row from my csv file that fits my condition and write to a new output file

Tags: python, list, csv

For example, i have the following dataset :

```
Date,Category,Amount,Description
06-06-2022,Food,300.0,celebration
02-09-2021,transport,3300.0,operation
```

And am required to delete one of the entries when condition 1 (e.g. description) and condition 2 (e.g. category) are met to get the following:

```
Date,Category,Amount,Description
06-06-2022,Food,300.0,celebration
```

so far, i have no issues with the conditions statement. However, when i execute, it would produced an output for the first line with commas for each individual character and no other info.

```
import os
import csv

with open("filename.csv","r+") as r, open("output.csv","w") as f:
     writer=csv.writer(f)
     for line in r:
            if condition_1 in line and condition_2 in line:
                print(line) #show the line that will be deleted
            else:
                writer.writerow(line) #write other lines to new file
                

os.remove('filename.csv')
os.rename('output.csv', "filename.csv")
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`csv` is an useful built-in standard library. With regards to learning it, you forgot to include `csv.reader`. Simply pass the file as an object to `csv.reader` similar to what you've done with `csv.writer`.

This is a working solution that you might want:

```py
# import os
import csv

with open("filename.csv","r+") as r, open("output.csv","w") as f:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    reader = csv.reader(r)
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
    for row in reader:
        # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
        # print(row)
        # print row as original text line
        # print(', '.join(row))
        if row[0] == '06-06-2022' and row[1] == 'Food':
            print(f'{row} to be deleted') #show the line that will be deleted
        else:
            writer.writerow(row)
        
# os.remove('filename.csv')
# os.rename('output.csv', "filename.csv")
```

Try it here
https://replit.com/@huydhoang/Delete-row-from-csv#main.py

Comment: csv is an incredibly useful library, I agree, but as you pointed out in my answer, in this case, it's probably not worth the import

Comment: it is in this specific use-case. I just thought it's a nice addition for when you might have say 2 columns both containing dates and want to have a condition checking specific dates in a specific column. Then `csv.reader` is great because it converts strings to lists.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a string of comma separated values in your `line` variable. You don't need the csv writer.

Instead you could try opening the file in append `open('output.csv', 'a')` mode and use `f.write(line)`

EDIT:

full code (working)

```py
import os

with open("filename.csv", "r") as r, open("output.csv", "a") as f:
    for line in r:
        if 'transport' in line and '3300.0' in line:
            print(line)  # show the line that will be deleted
        else:
            f.write(line)  # write other lines to new file

os.remove('filename.csv')
os.rename('output.csv', "filename.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks @Huy ‍♂️